# CoreBluetooth first pairing read request fails

Tags: ios, request, core-bluetooth, pairing-heap

I wonder about a behavior in CoreBluetooth that i can see since i updated to iOS8.2 in. I think that it worked correctly in iOS 8.1

Situation:

iPhone 6 iOS 8.2 working as CentralManager
Custom BLE-Device (CC2541)

Now...when i try to read a encrypted characteristic for the first time, i get the iOS Pairing request window as expected. But if type the correct pairing key the read request will fail for the first time. After that starting a second encrypted read request will succeed.

Is that an error in iOS 8.2 or am i confused? Does anybody here detected the same problem?!

Thanks...